# What is the bash equivalent of the csh 'where' builtin?

Tags: bash

I'm a long-time csh user trying (painfully) to convert to bash.  My apologies if this is a newbie type question, and I've tried to search the web but google isn't very helpful when the thing you're searching for also happens to be a common word.

What is the bash equivalent of the csh 'where' builtin?

```
"where: Reports all known instances of 'command', including aliases, builtins and executables in path."
```

I don't care that much about aliases and builtins.  I'm most interested in finding an executable that isn't reported by 'which' because there is another version of the executable earlier in the path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`type -a <program>` is the best way in `bash`.

Comment: How does this compare to `which -a <program>`?

Comment: `which -a` won't report shell built-ins but `type` will. For instance `$ type cd` will display `cd is a shell builtin` while `which` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The whereis command is part of the util-linux-ng package and is available from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng/.

(shamelessly stolen from its man page)